# MongoDB Improve Efficiency of this Collection Design

Tags: mongodb, database-design, nosql

Question: I'd like to know if my design here can be improved into something that is more efficient against my use cases. I believe there are better options, which I expect to come up in the answer. But if there aren't, I'd like to know which one of my options is the best suited for use cases below.

I'm designing the collection for a doctor appointment app. I have two options, but I can't tell which one the most efficient, as I'm new to NoSQL.
Now, the use case I need to cover are:

1. Query the appointment at a particular date
2. Query the appointment by doctor
3. Query the appointment by patient

I already have patients, doctors, medicalUnit and schedules collection. The design as such below. I just included the necessary ones :

```
// patient
{
  _id: id
  name: string
  // etc
}

// doctor
{
  _id: id
  name: string
  // etc
}

// medicalUnit
{
  _id: id
  name: string
  // etc
}

// schedule
{
  _id: id
  date: date
  event: {
    place: medicalUnit
    time: time
    duration: int
  }
  attendingPhysicianId: doctor._id
}
```

**Option 1**
I believe this option gives me good performance on read query, like the use case of query by date or by patient. I can query by doctor too, but I need to fetch from schedule database first by attendingPhysicianId, then use the scheduleId. Downside is I think I might put consistency to a risk here, especially when someone updates the schedule (e.g. change attending physician).

```
{
  _id: id,
  date: date,
  scheduleId: schedule._id
  examInfo: {
    doctorName: doctor.name
    medicalUnitName: medicalUnit.name
  }
  patientId: patient._id
}
```

**Option 2**
This one will have better consistency, but then I'll need multiple read from multiple collections. For example, query appointment by date means I need to fetch schedule by date first, then use the scheduleId to retrieve from this collection. Also, since the doctor information is very minimal in the schedule collection, I will also need to fetch the doctor collection.

```
{
  _id: id,
  scheduleId: schedule._id
  patientId: patient._id
}
```

The doctor collection might rarely be updated, so some of you might raise an option for an inmem caching. Yes that should works, but I'd like to see if it's possible not having other additional components.

Comment: To downvoter: Why the downvote? I did my research and ask only when things went stuck, At least give the explanation why you downvote it!

Answer (score 1):

There is no single correct answer for which design is best.

I would suggest considering how often each type of operation is executed, how long each type of operation takes, and compare the different options in terms of the effects on a single operation as well as the system as a whole.

As an example, consider a single possible difference.  Schedules need to be able to be filter by physician, and displaying a schedule record should include the physician's name.  So a few of the possible structures are:

#### Structure

A) Linked
- Schedules and physicians are stored in separate collections
- each schedule contains the id of the physician
- no piece of data is stored in 2 places (normalized)

B) Embedded
- Schedules are stored in their own collections
- The physicians collection is used only for reference when editing schedules
- all data for each physician is completely contained within each schedule document (completely de-normalized)

C) Hybrid
- Schedules and physicians are stored in separate collections
- each schedule contains the id of the physician, and enough information about the physician (i.e. name and specialty) for most display functions (partially de-normalized)

#### Tasks

Several frontend operations that are likely occur:

1. list schedules in a table-like or paged manner that displays the doctor's name and specialty in addition to the schedule details
2. display the full physician details for a specific schedule
3. change a physician's details

#### Operations

So we would then need to consider the backend operations that would be necessary for each type of frontend operation in each of the considered scenarios:

**Operation 1:**  Display a list of schedules with physician name
A)
- query the schedules collection to retrieve desired schedules
- for each schedule, query the physicians collection to retrieve the name matching the id

B)
- query the schedules collection to retrieve desired scheduled

C)
- query the schedules collection to retrieve desired scheduled

**Operation 2:**  Display physician detail for a specific schedule
A)
- query the schedules collection for a singled document
- query the physicians collection for the matching document

B)
- query the schedules collection for a single document

C)
- query the schedules collection for a single document
- query the physicians collection for the matching document

**Operation 3:**  Change a physician's details
A)
- update a single document in the physicians collection

B)
- update a single document in the physicians collection
- update all matching schedule documents with the new data

C)
- update a single document in the physicians collection
- If the physician's name or specialty was updated, update the matching schedule documents with the new data

For each of these, we then need to consider the count of operations:

1A)
- 1 read per schedule to retrieve schedule details
- 1 read per schedule to retrieve physician details

1B)
- 1 read per schedule to retrieve schedule + physician details

1C)
- 1 read per schedule to retrieve schedule + physician name/specialty

#### Impact

Then consider how often each of the frontend operations will occur, how much time/resource impact each backend operation has, and calculate the difference in impact both for a single instance of a frontend operation (proxy for the latency seen by the user) and overall for the time period (proxy for impact on the system).

The single-operation impact can be easily measured in a test environment.

Determining the overall system impact will require both extensive modeling, load testing, and prediction.

#### Summary

Each data structure is optimal for different applications and load patterns.  Determining which one is optimal for *your* application and load pattern is not something anyone can reliably tell you without intimate knowledge of your data and application well beyond what we would expect to gain from a question site such as this.